# Basis of metric space where balls dont have the center

Tags: general-topology, analysis, metric-spaces

I was asked this question

Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space, show that

$B=\{B_r (x)\setminus\{x\}:x\in X,r\in\mathbb{Q}^+\}$

Is a basis for $\tau_d$.

•) The set $B$ is obviously contained in $X$.

•) Im getting stuck showing that for every $U\in B$ and every $x\in X$ there exists a $b\in B$ such that $x\in b\subseteq U$. My attempted proof goes like this:

Let $x\in U$ so that $B_{\epsilon}(x)\subseteq U$ for some $\epsilon>0$. Let $y\in B_{\epsilon}(x)$, then we know that $B_r (y)\subseteq B_{\epsilon}(x)$ for some $r\in\mathbb{Q}^+$. It suffices to show that $B_r (y)\setminus\{y\}\subseteq U$.

Can anyone help me? ):

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! <> If $(X, d)$ is a discrete space, the punctured balls are either empty (if $r \leq 1$) or complements of singletons (if $1 < r$). If $X$ is uncountable, the family $B$ of punctured balls is not a basis for the discrete topology. Are there tacit conditions on $(X, d)$?

Comment: Hello! And thanks for the warm welcome :D No, its just some random metric space

Answer (score 1):

If we take $X=\{0,1,2\}$ in the discrete metric $d(x,y)=1 \iff x \neq y$ and $d(x,x)=0$ for all $x$, then $\mathcal{B} = \{\{2,3\},\{1,3\},\{1,2\}\}$ (all are of the form $B_r(x)\setminus \{x\}$ for $r\ge 1$; for $r<1$ we just get $\emptyset$ which we can omit), which is **not**  a base for some topology on $X$ as there is *no* member of $\mathcal{B}$ that contains $1 \in \{1,2\} \cap \{1,3\}$ and sits inside that intersection.

So as stated, the question is wrong.